# When did people first started to consider lead poisoning as a possible problem?

Tags: public-health

In our modern view lead poisoning is very bad for cognitive development and might even bring people to commit more crimes.

When in history did people first started to see lead as a possible problem?

Comment: See the answer here http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14593/did-lead-poisoning-contribute-to-the-fall-of-the-roman-empire

Comment: not sure what the connection is between lead poisoning and criminal activity. thought it had to do with cognitive development.

Comment: @user14394 I don't know how credible the link is, but [this article](http://www.motherjones.com/environment/2016/02/lead-exposure-gasoline-crime-increase-children-health) describes the idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According *[History of Lead Poisoning Around the World](https://www.lead.org.au/history_of_lead_poisoning_in_the_world.htm)* by Dr. Herbert L. Needleman, lead poisoning was first knowingly observed and recorded in a means which we can recover as early as 2000 BCE. Childhood lead poisoning was first discovered in 1892.  It was banned by an international agreement in 1925, but the United States waited until 1970 to ban it.

Comment: What exactly was banned? Lead? Lead poisoning? Some specific activity/technology that caused lead poisoning?

Comment: Lead was banned.